# Prevent Spray from modifying Authorization header value

Tags: scala, spray

We have an issue at the moment where we are passing a header into our spray server (either via tests or a running spray server and doing a curl)

Authorization: Basic somevalue

However, spray/runroute seems to modify the header to say "Basic somevalue:" (appending a colon).

We've worked around it by stripping off the colon.  I know this is a deviation from the Basic standard.  However, we're working with an existing header clients are sending us from a different system.  Also, we're trying to convert a spring/tomcat written system that does not modify the header, so it's hard to understand why spray would do this extra unnecessary logic

It seems "runRoute" attempts to parse and sanitise headers before giving it to the routes to run.  Since I want the header exactly, as is, is there a way to switch this off?

Note - this is definitely not our code modifying the header.  And no directive/route in use either.  If I rename the header to anything else, it does not modify the header.  If I remove Basic, the colon is not added.

I've looked at the spray code and this might be the class doing the modifications:

```
private[parser] trait AuthorizationHeader {
  this: Parser with ProtocolParameterRules with AdditionalRules ⇒
```